# Retrieval of highest value of a column and their dates

Tags: mysql

I have done code in MySQL to get the highest deaths value country-wise with their reporting date in MySQL. I am being able to get the highest deaths value but the dates values are returning wrong. Here is my MySQL code:

```
    SELECT 
    d.country_name, s.dt, MAX(s.deaths)
    FROM
    Demographics d 
    inner JOIN statistics s 
    On d.country_id=s.country_id
    GROUP BY country_name
    ORDER BY MAX(s.deaths) DESC;
```

The code is returning:

| country_name | dt | Max(s.deaths) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United_states | 2022-02-17 | 3635 |
| Germany | 2022-02-17 | 455 |
| Bangladesh | 2022-02-17 | 43 |

Here, the dt value is wrong. the result should be like this:

| country_name | dt | Max(s.deaths) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United_states | 2022-01-26 | 3635 |
| Germany | 2022-02-16 | 455 |
| Bangladesh | 2022-02-08 | 43 |

Here is my sample input:

```
    CREATE TABLE `demographics` (
    `country_id` char(3) NOT NULL,
    `country_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
     );

   CREATE TABLE `statistics` (
  `country_id` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `confirmed_cases` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `deaths` bigint(20) NOT NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO `demographics` (`country_id`, `country_name`) VALUES
  ('BGD', 'Bangladesh', 164700000, 148460, 1265),
  ('DEU', 'Germany', 83200000, 357386, 232),
  ('USA', ‘United_States’, 329500000, 9834000, 36);

  INSERT INTO `statistics` (`country_id`, `dt`, `confirmed_cases`, `deaths`) VALUES
  ('DEU', '2022-02-17', 235626, 261),
  ('DEU', '2022-02-16', 219972, 455),
  ('DEU', '2022-02-15', 159217, 243),
  ('DEU', '2022-02-14', 76465, 246),
  ('DEU', '2022-02-13', 62841, 42),
  ('DEU', '2022-02-12', 116810, 58),
  ('DEU', '2022-01-30', 92921, 42),
  ('DEU', '2022-01-19', 121952, 258),
  ('DEU', '2022-01-18', 95098, 199),
  ('DEU', '2022-01-17', 53916, 143),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-17', 3539, 20),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-16', 3929, 15),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-15', 4746, 34),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-14', 4692, 19),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-13', 4838, 28),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-12', 5023, 20),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-11', 5268, 27),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-10', 7264, 41),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-09', 8016, 33),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-08', 8354, 43),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-07', 9369, 38),
  ('BGD', '2022-02-06', 8345, 29),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-31', 13501, 31),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-30', 12183, 34),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-29', 10378, 21),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-28', 15440, 20),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-27', 15807, 15),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-20', 656, 8),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-19', 9500, 12),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-18', 8407, 10),
  ('BGD', '2022-01-17', 6676, 10),
  ('USA', '2022-02-17', 115149, 2802),
  ('USA', '2022-02-16', 141177, 3306),
  ('USA', '2022-02-15', 111151, 2850),
  ('USA', '2022-02-14', 87057, 1132),
  ('USA', '2022-02-13', 88494, 977),
  ('USA', '2022-02-12', 130169, 1555),
  ('USA', '2022-02-11', 168153, 2203),
  ('USA', '2022-02-05', 204770, 1761),
  ('USA', '2022-02-04', 306311, 2811),
  ('USA', '2022-02-03', 306317, 3279),
  ('USA', '2022-02-02', 325193, 3412),
  ('USA', '2022-02-01', 312473, 3582),
  ('USA', '2022-01-26', 555623, 3635),
  ('USA', '2022-01-25', 511029, 2972),
  ('USA', '2022-01-24', 292907, 1635),
  ('USA', '2022-01-23', 510878, 1394),
  ('USA', '2022-01-22', 670427, 1813)
  ('USA', '2022-01-17', 646886, 1283);
```

Comment: include `s.dt` in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are ok and return correct values:

[image]

Try to drop and recreate your data.

Comment: which editor did you use? because in db-fiddle and vscode both are returning wrong results

Comment: [sqliteonline](https://sqliteonline.com/)